# FIDO U2F in offline environment

Tags: offline, fido-u2f

I want to use the U2F protocol for an offline application.
This application has no connection to the internet, and I was wondering if its even possible to use U2F in an offline environment, as it requires some origin. Please note localhost is allowed and possibly can be used as origin but I'm unsure if that's secure or insecure and if it may lead to people being able to copy the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself yes its possible but you will have to program your own host that handles the appid acording to your needs